# How to take multiple search fields into consideration with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have three live filter search fields on a page. Triggered to search on keyup.

- Lead Author
- Subject
- Date

They each search a particular `<span>` element in a `<div>`

The problem I have is, say a wrong character is typed in one field and the user presses backspace. The code can't search for character before as it is now hidden.

How can I add the ability to take into account the other search fields content when searching on keyup?

[JSFiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/ARVft/)

Comment: Where is the connection of pressing backspace with having multiple fields?

Comment: When I press backspace in one search field I want to search the other two search fields and whatever remains in the current search field.

Comment: But don't you want this to happen for any key, any entered character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is when the user does do a back space is first show all of the authors again  and re run the search with the remaining text. Something similar to the below.

```
if (event.keyCode == 8){
   $("div.recordContainer span.listLeadAuthor").each(function(){
      $(this).parent().show();   
   });
}
```

I've updated your fiddle with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ARVft/1/) (just for the first search filter).

**EDIT**

Could you change the search function to the filter class and apply the same function to them all? I've updated another [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ARVft/2) this lets you use multiple search fields.

Comment: Hey, this is good but I want to search for whatever is entered in all fields, rather than just the current field.

Comment: the multiple `values` and `onBlur` events for the for the filters seems to be causing some issue with it... I would suggest using placeholders (and a modernizer plugin for old browser compatibility). I've updated the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ARVft/3/) and it seems to work for all 3 fields

Comment: Hey this is great it just seems to work for list lead author on all 3 search fields though rather than subject and date for the other two. I could have the fields clear instead.

Comment: Ah I see.. [please see this updated fiddle which searches the 3 fields respectively of the filter boxes.](http://jsfiddle.net/ARVft/5/)